# Delete a filled NSBezierPath

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, draw

I've drawn a red circle. Then I would like to delete it. How can I do that?

```
class Red: NSView {
    var red = 255
    var green = 0
    var blue = 0

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let circleFillColor = NSColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: 1)
        let cPath: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: dirtyRect)
        circleFillColor.set()
        cPath.fill()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let signal = Red(frame: NSRect(x: 146, y: 18, width: 25, height: 25))
    self.view.addSubview(signal)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `removeFromSuperview` method of the view to get if removed, as such:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var signal: Red?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.signal = Red(frame: NSRect(x: 146, y: 18, width: 25, height: 25))
        self.view.addSubview(signal!)
    }

    func deleteCircle() {
        self.signal?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.signal = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Or, depending on your need, you might just want to hide and show the view as necessary by setting `self.signal?.isHidden = true` and `self.signal?.isHidden = false`.

Comment: Whats the error? see this line `var signal: Red?` did you add this

Comment: Strange error, Paste your code to http://gist.github.com and share the link, let me have a look

Comment: Glad it helped!